# Plain text to HTML conversion in Outlook email

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, email, vsto

I am facing a situation to preserve the formatting of **plain text email** when displaying it as **virtual plain text** in C sharp. This is done during receiving in Outlook 2007 using VSTO.
The code below does not do the job, instead it converts the body into Times New Roman;Font Size 10 and displays it to the user.

```
string Text = "<html><body><p style=\"font-family:consolas;font-size:88%;\">" + mailItem.Body+ "</p></body></html>";

mailItem.HTMLBody = Text;

mailItem.HTMLBody = Regex.Replace(mailItem.HTMLBody, "(ASA[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9])", "<a href=\"http://stack.com/eg=$&\">$&</a>");
```

How can I rectify this problem?

**EDIT:**

**Input:**

ASAss87

ASAjj98

this is test input

**Output:**

ASAss87 ASAjj98 this is test input

EDIT 2:

**Input:**

ASAss87

ASAjj98

```
this is test input.
```

**Output:**

ASAss87

ASAjj98

```
   this is test input.
```

*Moves one or two spaces forward. I am using  tag.

Comment: What is the content of mailItem.HTMLBody before your code executes?..  Are you sure it does not already contain HTML, BODY, and style elements?

Comment: mailItem.Body contains only plain text, whereas mailItem.HTMLbody contains HTML and body and style elements.

Comment: in that case, shouldn't your first line reference `mailItem.Body` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your feedback in the comments, try changing your first line to use `Body` instead of `HTMLBody`:

```
string Text = "<html><body><p style=\"font-family:consolas;font-size:88%;\">" + mailItem.Body+ "</p></body></html>";
```

Edit: Since the plain text contains line-breaks, maybe you should use a `<pre>` tag instead of a `<p`> tag, to prevent it from putting everything on one line.

```
string Text = "<html><body><pre style=\"font-family:consolas;font-size:88%;\">" + mailItem.Body+ "</pre></body></html>";
```

Edit2: Alternatively, you can replace all line-breaks with `<br>` tags.

```
string Text = "<html><body><p style=\"font-family:consolas;font-size:88%;\">" + mailItem.Body.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<BR>") + "</p></body></html>";
```

Comment: After changes to the code it works, but the formatting gets lost.(edited in question about this)

Comment: @thinkcool updated my answer with 2 approaches for your latest edit.

Comment: How can I add line breaks <br> to my code. I do not know where the line is going to break.

Comment: @thinkcool by replacing the existing line-breaks in the plain text, i.e. `\n` or `\r` (or using Environment.NewLine).  editing my answer again.

Comment: switched last example back to a `<p>` tag.

Comment: @Fosco let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1160/discussion-between-thinkcool-and-fosco)